# Avoiding Loops to Generate a Complex Dataframe with Nested Lists

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

Here is a kind of DF, I have to generate to store simulations data).

```
    nbSimul         <- 100
    nbSampleSizes   <- 4
    nbCensoredRates <- 4
    sampleSize      <- c(100, 50, 30, 10)
    censoredRate    <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8)

    df.sampled      <- data.frame(cas              = numeric()  ,
                                  distribution     = character(),
                                  simul            = numeric()  ,
                                  sampleSize       = numeric()  ,
                                  censoredRate     = numeric()  ,
                                  dta              = I(list())  ,
                                  quantileLD       = I(list())  ,
                                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    v <- 0  # Scenario indicator
    for(k in 1:nbCensoredRates){
         for(j in 1:nbSampleSizes){
              for(i in 1:nbSimul){

                   # Scenario Id + Other info
                   v <- v + 1
                   df.sampled[v,"cas"]   <- v
                   df.sampled[v,"distribution"] <- "logNormal"
                   df.sampled[v,"simul"]        <- i
                   df.sampled[v,"sampleSize"]   <- sampleSize[j]
                   df.sampled[v,"censoredRate"] <- censoredRate[k]

                   X <- rlnorm(sampleSize[j], meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)

                   estimatedLD <- array(9)
                   for(w in 1:9){
                        estimatedLD[w] <- quantile(X, probs=censoredRate[k], type=w)[[1]]
                   }

                   df.sampled$dta[v]             <- list(X)
                   df.sampled$quantileLD[v]      <- list(estimatedLD[1:9])
              }
         }
}
```

Which is quite difficult to read.
I would like to find a way to avoid loops, and to reference easily scenarios (v) and attached variables.
Any idea?

Comment: have you tried something around `expand.grid`, at least for the triple loop? then, if I understand properly, `v` is the row id of `df.sampled`?

Comment: My humble opinion.  Leave it the way it is.  It's not really that hard to read.  I find it pretty easy to read.  Getting rid of the loop won't speed anything up because you are doing a lot of work in the inner loop.  I don't understand what you mean by "reference easily scenarios and attached variables".  But my opinion here is that if it works, your time is better spent on something else, it's good enough as is.